# Android checkbox ui change

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox

How can I have a checkbox in my ui alter my ui live? For example, if the box is unchecked I want a spinner to be displayed, and if the box is checked I want a text box to be displayed in place of the spinner. I know how to create the checkbox and check its status but I don't know how to hide and reveal other elements in an activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an OnClickListener for the checkbox.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 1):

If you add your switchable layout inside a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or similiar, you can easily toggle the visibility.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In you XML you should set the attribute `android:visibility="gone"` and change it at runtime.